# 5 Google Devloper Account Will Be Terminated

Tags: keystore, google-play-console, android-keystore, google-developers-console

I am doing applications without Coding by means of a platform without writing code at all, recently nearly 5 Google Play Console accounts were closed at the same time!
Note that:
The name is different
The visa is different
The email is different and even the backup email is different
The phone number is different
The device is different
Internet is different (ip address)
And even some accounts in it another country

Everything else is completely different for each account

When I searched, I found someone saying that using the same keystore on more than one account. "If one account is terminated, all accounts will be terminated because of the keystore."

And when I asked the technical support of the platform, they said that the keystore used is the same for all applications on the platform!

Please help me, is that the reason they closed at the same time?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a programming question: noone will be able to help you here. Reach out to Google support for answers.

Comment: I sent Google more than one message, and I did not receive any response!

Comment: The reason for the accounts being closed should have been sent to you by email when the accounts were closed.

Comment: @hasanah... the google respond is actually a bot. we can't hope for it.
So how are you right now? Is it solved?